# Jordan Form Superdiagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

How do you know how many of the super diagonal entries in the Jordan Form are zeros and how many are ones, and where they are placed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> *How many ones?*

Each $k\times k$ Jordan block has $k-1$ ones on its superdiagonal. To get the total number, you just add up all the results from all blocks.

> *How many zeros?*

If you find the total number of $1$'s for all blocks, and subtract this from the total number of $n-1$ superdiagonal entries, you have the number of zeros.

> *where are they placed?*

The ones are placed *on the superdiagonals of Jordan blocks*. The zeros are placed on the remaining superdiagonal positions.

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, I think you might have to draw a few Jordan canonical forms and draw squares around the Jordan blocks. It should be very straightforward where the ones go.