# Jordan canonical form of matrix $A$ involving power

Tags: matrices

Given matrix $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix with the same property as shown in the link:
[Jordan Form Superdiagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609536/jordan-form-superdiagonal) where $A$ has $n - 1$ ones in upper superdiagonal entries.

Then for every $i$, what is the Jordan canonical form for $A^i$?

Comment: Bare problem statements like this with no context or any indication of effort on your part to solve the problem can look like attempts to outsource your school work. Such questions are not well received here, and there’s a pretty good chance that this question will get closed. See [How To Ask A Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hints: What are the eigenvectors of $A$? Does raising $A$ to a power change the dimension of the associated eigenspace, i.e., does $A^n$ have any eigenvectors that aren’t also eigenvectors of $A$?